# How to apply highlighting match characters within the autosuggestion list in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a search engine, and want to change the color of matching characters

I'm using regex to matching an input value with array items, I've searched about solving a highlighting issue and I found this: `item.replace(regex, '<mark>$1</mark>')` but I don't know how to implement it.

```
  onTextChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    let suggestions = [];
    if(value.length > 0) {

        const regex = new RegExp(`${value}`, 'i');
        suggestions = this.items.sort().filter(v => regex.test(v));

        this.setState(() => ({ suggestions, textValue: value }));
     }
    this.setState(() => ({ suggestions, textValue: value }));

   }

//this function return autosuggestion list

    renderSuggestions () {
     const {suggestions} = this.state;
     if(suggestions.length !== 0) {

//suggestionSelected() hidden suggestion list after clicking

     return(
        <div className="auto-suggestions">
            <ul>
            {suggestions.map((item) =>
            <li key={item} className="suggestion-item" onClick={()=> 
               this.suggestionSelected(item)}>{item}</li>)}
             </ul>
          </div>
        );
       }
      }

//within the render() I have:

    const {suggestions, textValue} = this.state;
    <div className="container">
            <input type="text" onChange={this.onTextChange} value= {textValue} />
             {this.renderSuggestions()} 
             {this.showUsers()}

    </div>
```

I'm not sure where and how could solve this problem, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to render the highlighted text in a plain html, you can have this sample

```
 safeHTML(item) {
   return item.replace(new RegExp(this.state.selectedText, 'gi'),'<strong>$&</strong>')
  }

  getHighlighted(item){
     return (
      <p key={item}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html : this.safeHTML(item)
        }} />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {
        this.state.suggestions.map(s => {
          return this.getHighlighted(s)
        })
      }
    </div>;
  }
```

PS: You need a sanitized data for security

Hopefully this will help :)

Comment: it's a great way, it's work perfectly now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems to solve: (1) extract the matching substring in `suggestions` and (2) highlight the matching substring in your UI.

You can use `String.prototype.split` instead of `RegExp.prototype.test` to split the string with matching regex and prepare necessary data for rendering:

```
onTextChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    let suggestions = [];
    if(value.length > 0) {
        const regex = new RegExp(`${value}`, 'i');
        suggestions = this.items.sort().map(v => {
            const arr = v.split(regex);
            return arr.map(substr => ({
                value: substr,
                isMatched: regex.test(substr)
            }))
        });
        suggestions = suggestions.filter(arr => arr.some(({ isMatched}) => isMatched))

        this.setState(() => ({ suggestions, textValue: value }));
     }
    this.setState(() => ({ suggestions, textValue: value }));

   }
```

then print out the suggestions list:

```
   renderSuggestions () {
     const {suggestions} = this.state;
     if(suggestions.length !== 0) {

     return(
        <div className="auto-suggestions">
            <ul>
            {suggestions.map((item) =>
                <li key={item} className="suggestion-item" onClick={()=> 
                    this.suggestionSelected(item)}>
                    {item.map(({ value, isMatched}) => 
                        {isMatched ?
                            <span>{value}</span> :
                            <strong>{value}</strong>
                        }
                    )}
               </li>)}
             </ul>
          </div>
        );
       }
      }
```